# Converting a time measurement to a variable in R

Tags: r, time

I am looking to generate variables in R for cross country results and wish to convert times to a variable. For example I want to be able to compare "17:43" (MM:SS) to "19:14". However R seems to only do times with regards to points during the day (i.e 1300 = 1:00pm). Does anyone know of a way to convert these times to values to be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lubridate` package to parse values like this. It has a special class for "duration". You can use the `ms()` to parse your times (where the "m" stands for minutes and the "s" for seconds).

```
library(lubridate)
ms("17:43")
# [1] "17M 43S"
ms("19:14")
# [1] "19M 14S"
```